# References to trait objects are not cloneable

Tags: traits, rust

Why references to trait objects are not cloneable? This code compiles:

```rust
struct Test;

fn clone_vec<'a>(v: Vec<&'a Test>) -> Vec<&'a Test> {
    v.clone()
}

fn main() {
}
```

This one doesn't:

```rust
trait Test {
    fn do_smt(&self);
}

fn clone_vec<'a>(v: Vec<&'a Test>) -> Vec<&'a Test> {
    v.clone()
}

fn main() {
}
```

Error:

```
main3.rs:7:5: 7:14 error: failed to find an implementation of trait std::clone::Clone for &'a Test<no-bounds>
main3.rs:7     v.clone()
               ^~~~~~~~~
```

However, `Clone` trait is implemented for any kind of reference, as far as I can see:

```rust
impl<'a, T> Clone for &'a T {
    /// Return a shallow copy of the reference.
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> &'a T { *self }
}
```

I just don't see why `&'a Test` where `Test` is a trait is not cloneable. It's just a pointer after all. This restriction prohibits, for example, going from `&[&'a SomeTrait]` to `Vec<&'a SomeTrait>`, which looks like an obvious conversion, or cloning a `Vec<&'a SomeTrait>`, as in the example.

This is very strange provided that I can implement `clone_vec()` myself, without `Clone`:

```rust
fn clone_vec<'a>(v: Vec<&'a Test>) -> Vec<&'a Test> {
    let mut result = Vec::new();
    for &e in v.iter() {
        result.push(e);
    }
    result
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Clone` is a normal library trait, and requires normal (library) implementations, for all types. For example, `Clone` is implemented for `&T` [right here](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/0c691df8acaf10aa3721476e5d7fafcee11b0aaa/src/libstd/clone.rs#L60), in the form:

```
impl<'a, T> Clone for &'a T {
    /// Return a shallow copy of the reference.
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> &'a T { *self }
}
```

Hence, everything of the form `&T` is `Clone`able... where `T` a concrete type. And that's the clincher: `&Trait` is not (yet) a type of the form `&T` with `T = Trait` (but rather an "atomic"/primitive type that can't be separated into parts), so it is not covered by that `impl`.

We require dynamically sized types (DST) for the compiler to be able to reason about passing just plain old `Trait` around as a generic parameter (Nick Cameron is actually hard at work at some parts of the DST implementation, so this will hopefully happen soon).

You can, however, manually implement `Clone` for your traits of interest, e.g. the following works well:

```
trait Foo {}

impl<'a> Clone for &'a Foo {
    fn clone(&self) -> &'a Foo {
        *self
    }
}
```

However, it only works for traits defined in your current crate, or else the compiler has concerns about coherence (e.g. changing `Foo` to `Eq` in the `impl` above causes `error: cannot provide an extension implementation where both trait and type are not defined in this crate`).

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. I'll be waiting for the DST. It seems it will be a spectacular change, so many new features easing one's life :) thank you very much!